# Default value for nested dataclasses

Tags: python, nested, python-dataclasses

I got the following dataclasses in Python:

```
@dataclass
class B(baseClass):

  d: float
  e: int


@dataclass
class A(baseClass):

  b: B
  c: str
```

I have this configured so that the baseClass allows to get the variables of each class from a config.json file. This file contains the following nested dictionary.

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
       "d": a_float_value
       "e": a_int_value
    }
    c: a_string_value
}
```

But the key "b" can be an empty dict.

```
{
  a: {
    b: {}
    c: a_string_value
}
```

But how do I integrate this into my dataclasses?
I tried

```
@dataclass
class B(baseClass):

  d: float
  e: int


@dataclass
class A(baseClass):

  b: Optional[B] = {}
  c: str
```

and

```
@dataclass
class B(baseClass):

  d: float
  e: int


@dataclass
class A(baseClass):

  b: B = field(default_factory=dict)
  c: str
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something like this by explicitly using the field class from `dataclasses`:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class B:

  d: float
  e: int

@dataclass
class A:
  c: str
  b: Optional[B] = field(default_factory=dict)


obj = A(c='sds')
print(obj.b)
```

Output was an empty dictionary for b variable.

Comment: This gives me the error "Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]", variable has type "Optional[B]")". What does this mean?

Comment: ah yes that's cos B is a type of B class and the default we're setting is a dictionary. You can't do that!! Either you have to have something like None for a class type varialble, else if its a dictionary then you can use {}. I"ve updated the answer. You can still use to convert the class to dict, but then that'll bring in all the other variables inside the class, and not the expected empty dictionary in your usecase

Comment: @Steven01123581321 i have updated the answer. Can you try this pls?\